# PHP curl broken

Tags: curl

Curl seems to hang when making calls. This is breaking wordpress/wp-admin sites & the twillio helper library used for IP-SMS.

This issue appeared after installing vsftpd and creating new users.

script to test curl: (from google)

```
function nxs_cURLTest($url, $msg, $testText){  
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  $response = curl_exec($ch); 
  $errmsg = curl_error($ch); 
  $cInfo = curl_getinfo($ch); 
  curl_close($ch); 
  echo "Testing ... ".$url." - ".$cInfo['url']."<br />";
  if (stripos($response, $testText)!==false) 
    echo "....".$msg." - OK<br />"; 
  else 
  { 
    echo "....<b style='color:red;'>".$msg." - Problem</b><br /><pre>"; 
    print_r($errmsg); 
    print_r($cInfo); 
    print_r(htmlentities($response)); 
    echo "</pre>There is a problem with cURL. You need to contact your server admin or hosting provider.";
  }
}

  nxs_cURLTest("http://www.nextscripts.com/", "HTTPS to NXS", "Social Networks");
  nxs_cURLTest("http://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/", "HTTP to Google", "Mountain View, CA");
  nxs_cURLTest("https://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/", "HTTPS to Google", "Mountain View, CA");
  nxs_cURLTest("https://www.facebook.com/", "HTTPS to Facebook", 'id="facebook"');
  nxs_cURLTest("https://graph.facebook.com/", "HTTPS to API (Graph) Facebook", 'get');  
  nxs_cURLTest("https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/", "HTTPS to LinkedIn", 'rel="canonical" href="https://www.linkedin.com/');
```

output:

```
Testing ... http://www.nextscripts.com/ - http://www.nextscripts.com/
....HTTPS to NXS - OK
Testing ... http://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/ - http://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/
....HTTP to Google - OK
Testing ... https://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/ - https://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/
....HTTPS to Google - Problem
Failed to connect to www.google.com port 443: Connection timed outArray
(
    [url] => https://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 5.003154
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004183
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
There is a problem with cURL. You need to contact your server admin or hosting provider.Testing ... https://www.facebook.com/ - https://www.facebook.com/
....HTTPS to Facebook - Problem
Failed to connect to www.facebook.com port 443: Connection timed outArray
(
    [url] => https://www.facebook.com/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 5.003227
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004192
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
There is a problem with cURL. You need to contact your server admin or hosting provider.Testing ... https://graph.facebook.com/ - https://graph.facebook.com/
....HTTPS to API (Graph) Facebook - Problem
Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Connection timed outArray
(
    [url] => https://graph.facebook.com/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 5.003548
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004187
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
There is a problem with cURL. You need to contact your server admin or hosting provider.Testing ... https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/ - https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/
....HTTPS to LinkedIn - Problem
Failed to connect to www.linkedin.com port 443: Connection timed outArray
(
    [url] => https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 5.003194
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004179
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
There is a problem with cURL. You need to contact your server admin or hosting provider.
```

Curl is still installed on my server, i have verified this through `phpinfo();`

reinstalling the curl module did not help.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: `Failed to connect to X port 443: Connection timed out`

Comment: yes, the connection is apparently trying to go over a secure port. Meaning this is an issue with my SSL certificate?

Comment: check `network`, `firewall`, etc... in shell try `curl -I www.google.com`

Comment: I've opened port 443 to all outgoing on my AWS-EC2 instance. that command outputted Failed to connect to www.google.com port 80: connection timed out. @alexus

Comment: `Security Group` should not be blocking anything out, if you're running firewall on your Linux, disable it temporary just to pinpoint where actual issue is.

Comment: Fixed, after doing some rationalization i figured all outgoing traffic should be open. That fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Post in answers, you deserve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Failed to connect to X port 443: Connection timed out
```

this looks like more of a networking issue, rather then `php` and/or `curl`, one should try to replicate it via shell's `curl` and/or `wget`.